# How to replicate SQL Server rowversion behaviour for some fields only

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, database-trigger, rowversion

SQL Server version 10.50.4000.

I have a table:

```
create table people
(
    national_id char(16),
    full_name char(255),
    last_visited datetime
)
```

I want to add a field that will work exactly like a [rowversion field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms182776.aspx), except:

1. It must update only when last_visited is changed.
2. It needn't be unique on the database but must be unique on the table.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to work "exactly" as a rowversion field? rowversions are unique on the database. Do you need that uniqueness?

Comment: @JesúsLópez Thanks for question. It must be unique on the table. Doesn't have to be unique on the database.